# sp_help for MySql?

Tags: mysql

I learned about this:

```
desc survey.bb_data
```

through SO, but this only tells you what the field names are but doesn't show constraints, etc.

Maybe I'm being naive about this but shouldn't there be more data (like FK's, etc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE survey.bb_data
```

That should show all field types and foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the following query:

```
SHOW COLUMNS IN survey.bb_data
```

Comment: do you mean `survey.bb_data`